# Class was not found in the chain configured namespaces (zend framework 2 and doctrine 2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I get the following error when I try to use an entity in my controller:

> The class 'Application\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2_pr6\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:37

My `module.config.php` configuration includes

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'application_entities' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ),
    ),
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMysql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '3306',
                'user' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'dbname' => 'zf2',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'orm_default' => array(
    'drivers' => array(
        'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities',
    ),
),
```

I've also created a paste bin of other relevant files

- [Application\Entity\User](http://pastebin.com/UTYZ3KXa)
- [Application\Contorller\IndexController](http://pastebin.com/CeDDSntq)

How can I resolve this error add my driver to the chain of configured namespaces?

Comment: i forgot to copy on my controller from pastebin use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, it was included in my code

Comment: Are you using `DoctrineORMModule`? If yes, you have to register the `Application\Entity` namespace to the mapping driver. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#entities-settings

Comment: Hi Bram, i'm using DoctrineORMModule and it's configured according to your documentation. You can see my module.config.php here: http://pastebin.com/fHD4sWdd Also the mapping is ok according to orm:validate-schema

Comment: @BeniaminGheorghita I've updated your question to better explain your issue. If you feel the edit it incorrect feel free to revert or edit my changes. In future, please add any relevant code directly within your question so that other people, perhaps with the same issue, will not have to deal with dead links etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect. At the moment you have the 'orm_default' config under the 'doctrine' key - Meaning the driver is never added to Doctrine.

You need to have the driver configuration and the 'orm_default' config sitting at the same level, under `doctrine/driver`.

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(

        'application_entities' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ),

        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities',
            ),
        ),
    )
),
```